# Can not understand why `redis + gevent + multithreading` performence is so pool

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, redis, gevent

### Question

I am trying to use gevent to improve my programe to interact with redis, but when use gevent + redis-py in `multi threading` scenario, i found that the performence is so pool. When i comment the `monkey.patch_all()`, the performence is good, i cannot understand why.

### ENV and dependency

- python: 2.7
- redis-py: 3.0.1
- gevent: 1.2.1

### Example code:

```py
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()   # comment this code, the result will be diffrent

import redis
import time
import threading
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s: %(message)s", level=logging.INFO, datefmt="%H:%M:%S")

# Redis will use default connection pool
conn = redis.Redis(host="127.0.0.1", port=6379, socket_timeout=5, socket_connect_timeout=5)

conn.set("key", "value", ex=50000)


def get_key():
    t = time.time()
    conn.get("key")
    t1 = time.time() - t
    if t1 > 1:
        logging.info("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  get key fron redis to slow %s" % t1)
    else:
        logging.info("----------------------------------  get key cost time is %s " % t1)


for i in range(1000):
    x = threading.Thread(target=get_key, args=())
    x.start()


logging.info("Main    : all done")
```

### Test result

#### without `monkey.patch_all()`

```py
from gevent import monkey
# monkey.patch_all()
```

without `monkey.patch_all()`, the redis delay is very small.

```
13:45:10: ----------------------------------  get key cost time is 0.000197887420654 
13:45:10: ----------------------------------  get key cost time is 0.000231981277466 
13:45:10: ----------------------------------  get key cost time is 0.000230073928833 
13:45:10: ----------------------------------  get key cost time is 0.000216960906982 
13:45:10: ----------------------------------  get key cost time is 0.000287055969238 
13:45:10: ----------------------------------  get key cost time is 0.000190019607544 
13:45:10: ----------------------------------  get key cost time is 0.000202178955078 
13:45:10: ----------------------------------  get key cost time is 0.000118970870972 
13:45:10: ----------------------------------  get key cost time is 0.000120878219604 
13:45:10: Main    : all done
```

#### with `monkey.patch_all()`

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
```

the redis delay is very big, and if i adjust the `1000` threading to bigger, the delay will be more bigger.

```
13:46:19: ----------------------------------  get key cost time is 0.217961072922 
13:46:19: ----------------------------------  get key cost time is 0.217952013016 
13:46:19: ----------------------------------  get key cost time is 0.218060970306 
13:46:19: ----------------------------------  get key cost time is 0.216876029968 
13:46:19: ----------------------------------  get key cost time is 0.216850996017 
13:46:19: ----------------------------------  get key cost time is 0.216836929321 
13:46:19: ----------------------------------  get key cost time is 0.216396093369 
13:46:19: ----------------------------------  get key cost time is 0.216381072998
```

Comment: This answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10663498/1055722

Comment: thank you very much. yes, i also searched this issue, and i also had try it, but the result is same, it do not improve the performence.

Comment: Have you tried accumulating your timing results and print them at the end rather than logging from each thread/greenlet and seeing what the difference is?

Comment: yes, it is. the result is same.